# isset get variable and 0 on ternary elvis operator

Tags: php, get, ternary-operator

I have this code:

```
$var=(isset($_GET[var])?$_GET[var]:1);
```

I think it should works like this:

- if url has not var (file.php), then $var=1.
- if url has var (file.php?var=0), $var=0.

What I get is:

- if url has not var (file.php), then $var=1.
- **if url has var (file.php?var=0), $var=1.**

$_GET[var] is set! and it is 0, why I get 1?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Close. Your parentheses were just a bit off. And is `var` a constant?

```
$var = isset($_GET['var']) ? $_GET['var'] : 1;
```

You either meant string `'var'` of variable `$var` I imagine.

Comment: Doesn't matter about the parenthesis really.

Comment: @Qirel, thanks.  Good to know. Assumed it would be a syntax error but did wonder.

Comment: If it was a syntax-error, it wouldn't have worked at all ;-) Granted, the parenthesis around the entire ternary isn't needed, but it doesn't hurt either.

Comment: And actually, I think PHP is smart enough to figure out that `$_GET[var]` should be `$_GET['var']` - it will issue a notice though. Edit: Actually, because `var` has a special meaning, it won't work and needs to be quoted!

Comment: @Qirel Actually... if we are getting nit picky :).... var is a reserved word.  I get parse error: `unexpected 'var' (T_VAR), expecting ']'` Otherwise yes, would be notice: `Use of undefined constant...`